# Why do we increment the version in Docker Compose? (Version 1, 2, and 3)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Currently learning about Docker and I was wondering why we increment the version in Docker-Compose.

There are Three docker versions: 1, 2, and 3. Why do we have only 3 versions? ... Does version 3 give you more options?

Is it necessary to upgrade the Docker Compose version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to the version of the file format of docker-compose.It has changed through time to add more options, but when doing so they also changed the way some of the functionality was declared, when that happens they change the major version.

The older versions are maintained o that backwards-compatibility to docker-compose files people were already using keep working with newer versions of docker and docker-compose.

If you are starting to learn, or starting a new project, the best practice is to use the latest version available.

In  the [documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) you have more information about the file format of docker-compose and what's available in each version (3.7 as the writing of this comment).

Answer (score 2):

Those are not versions of the docker itself. Those are versions of the configuration file format.

Each version defines which options you can use in the docker-compose.yml file. For example, see this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/